# Creating default object from empty value in Laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want to Update this data in database.

error :

```
ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value
```

i get error in this line :

```
$user->name = $request->name;
```

My Controller code is :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'mobile' => 'required|numeric|regex:/(0)[0-9]/|not_regex:/[a-z]/|digits:11',
        'national_code' => 'required|numeric|regex:/(0)[0-9]/|not_regex:/[a-z]/|digits:10',
        'avatar' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    $id = (int)$id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->mobile = $request->mobile;
    $user->national_code = $request->national_code;
    $user->province = $request->province;
    $user->city = $request->city;
    $user->address = $request->address;
    $user->postcode = $request->postcode;
    $user->active = $request->active;
    $user->avatar = $request->avatar;


    if(! is_null($request->password)) {
        $request->validate([
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $user->password = $request->password;
    }

    $user->active = $request->active ? 1 : 0;

    if ($request->role_id) {
        $user->syncRoles($request->role_id);
    }
    $user->save();

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Success !',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect(route('management.users.index'))->with($notification);
}
```

Route :

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Thank you

Comment: could you add this error ?

Comment: @Joseph i added.

Comment: could you add your route to this method?

Comment: I don't think Route has anything to do with this error !! But i added.

Comment: first update your function header to this `public function update(Request $request, User $user)` and you could use it directly without useing `findorfail`

Comment: @Joseph i changed my code, please see Answer.

Comment: there is no `first` in your method at all this error comes from another place

Comment: No, there is no such thing

Comment: Can't someone else guide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = User::find($id)
```

or this:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
```

And check if in your User Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name','mobile', 'national_code', 'city', 'province', 'address', 
     'postcode', 'active', 'avatar',
];
```

Comment: thanks, User::find($id) worked, but User::findOrFail($id); have problem ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent in documentation you can show why not work, findOrFail is for Exception capture